# Generator in if-statement in python

Tags: python, list, if-statement, generator, list-comprehension

**Or How to if-statement in a modified list.**

I've been reading StackOverflow for a while (thanks to everyone). I love it. I also seen that you can post a question and answer it yourself. Sorry if I duplicate, but I didn't found this particular answer on StackOverflow.

---

- How do you verify if a element is in a list but modify it in the same time?

My problem:

```
myList = ["Foo", "Bar"]
if "foo" in myList:
  print "found!"
```

As I don't know the case of the element in the list I want to compare with lower case list. The obvious but ugly answer would be:

```
myList = ["Foo", "Bar"]
lowerList = []

for item in myList:
  lowerList.append(item.lower())

if "foo" in lowerList:
  print "found!"
```

Can I do it better ?

Comment: Minor point: while you can use 'list' as a variable name, you probably shouldn't as doing so overshadows the name of the built-in type.

Comment: Nice catch Peter: I actually think that's a moderate to major point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if any(s.lower() == "foo" for s in list): print "found"
```

Comment: note: any() is slightly better than list comprehension because it stops as soon as the first item is found. Also it won't create a disposable temporary list.

Comment: @Philippe I've just checked that both answers (this and yours) behaves similary. `in` also stops when the first element is found.

Comment: @Philippe, interesting, I haven't thought of writing it this way. They seem equivalent to me.

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions:

```
mylist = ["Foo", "Bar"]
lowerList = [item.lower() for item in mylist]
```

Then you can do something like `if "foo" in lowerlist` or bypass the temporary variable entirely with `if "foo" in [item.lower() for item in mylist]`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
theList = ["Foo", "Bar"]
lowerCaseSet = set(x.lower for x in theList)

if "foo" in lowerCaseSet:
   print "found"
```

BTW. you shouldn't call your variable `list` as this word is already used by `list` type.

Answer (score 0):

This combines the memory advantages of a generator expression with the speed gains from removing duplicates:

```
if "foo" in (s.lower() for s in set(list)): print "found"
```

Comment: Why are you making a set of the list?

Comment: Two reasons. Sets have a lookup time of O(1) vs a list, that has a lookup time on O(n). Generating a set also removes any duplicates of the initial data.

Comment: You aren't looking up anything in the set, you just iterate over it.

Comment: Well, we'll searching for something within the collection.

Comment: The problem is that you create the set, but then produce a generator expression out of it. The expression (s.lower() for s in set(list)) will not produce another set. It will produce a generator expression. The in operator will then process that by looking at each and every entry.

Comment: To use a set you need: if "foo" in set(s.lower() for s in list): print "found" (but it takes O(n) time to construct the set so its only worthwhile if you are going to be checking multiple items)

Comment: If you doubt, please time a test case, in my test I found the set version to be 10 times slower then the non set version.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this - of course generating the set is O(n).

Comment: Yes, well, I couldn't stand someone being wrong on the internet. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use list as variable name, here is version which puts generator to variable and demonstrates, that generation stopped after finding the answer and did not exhaust the generator:

```
list_to_search = ["Foo", "Bar"]
lowergen = (item.lower() for item in list_to_search)
if "foo" in lowergen:
  print "found!"
print next(lowergen), 'is next after it'
```